Is it correct to say "that is a backward seven" or "that seven is backward""?
"upside down" is an adverb but also an adjective. So is "backward".
And the dictionary says

upside down adjective [not usually before noun]

The painting looks like it's upside down to me.
It seems we can not say "that's an upside-down painting".
However, the dictionary also says

backward adjective  /ˈbækwəd/  /ˈbækwərd/ ​[only before noun]

She strode past him without a backward glance.
It seems we can not say "his glance is backward".

My daughter wrote number 7 like that.
Is it correct to say "that is a backward seven" or "that seven is backward""?

Don't overstate the significance of one "throwaway" comment in one dictionary (upside down - not usually before noun). Here's a link to probably hundreds of written instances of upside down newspaper. In the case of your "7" example, both forms are fine. Here are plenty of written references to ...letter is backward. It just so happens her glance was backward isn't remotely idiomatic, but "only before noun" is misleading there.

'It seems we can not say "that's an upside-down painting" - yes you can. an actual, reported case of an upside-down painting. At a 1915 art exhibition in Grand Rapids, Michigan, "The Blue Pool," by George Bellows, was hung in a conspicuous location. Several artists gave talks at the event in which they referenced it, describing it as "modern in treatment." It was only after three weeks that the exhibitors realized they had hung the painting upside-down. When righted, the seemingly abstract swatches of color transformed into a more familiar scene of a pool of water surrounded by rocks.

A more formal term for 'backwards' is 'reversed'.

You can also say 'back to front' or 'the wrong way round'.

I think it's primarily a British usage, but upside-down pudding was a common dessert in my childhood.

To clarify - an 'upside-down pudding' is designed to be turned out of the baking dish for serving, so that the fruit arranged in the bottom of the dish is now on the top of the pudding.

is it "upside down" or "backward"?.
.
You cannot call your daughter's "7", upside down as it means legs up and head down (image).



You can call it, "backward", because mirror writing is also called backward writing.
*Leonardo Da Vinci wrote backward.".
My daughter wrote a backward 7.
Or.
That 7 is written backward..

Ref. https://www.mos.org/leonardo/activities/mirror-writing.html#:~:text=Leonardo's%20Private%20Notes,write%20in%20the%20normal%20direction.

You can also express it as, "My daughter wrote an inverted seven.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
inverted.
adjective   formal.
changed from the normal position by being turned upside down or being arranged in the opposite order:
Cover the bowl with an inverted plate..
The building is shaped like an inverted pyramid..

"Inverted seven" means both "upside down" or a mirror image sideways,

I think this answer is nonsense. The OP never suggested his "7" was upside down, only backward. Which is a perfectly valid thing to say, both as attributive and predicative adjective (it's a backward 7, the 7 is backward).

@FumbleFingers I changed the answer to include backward.


That's a painting of an upside-down tree.

Using upside-down as an attributive modifier is colloquial, informal. It appears normally after the copula:

In that painting, the tree is upside-down.

Some people will say "backward" and others "backwards":

That's a backward(s) seven.

This too is a somewhat informal way of stating the fact.
The tone is conversational.
.
